# How Does One Calculate Angular Defect?

Tags: geometry

If I were to draw a 1km square on the earth what would the angles of the corners be?  Obviously they would be a little greater than 90-deg but how would I calculate the angle exactly?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by a "square."  Except in very special locations there exist no figures whose sides are equal-length geodesics and all of whose angles are equal. What parts of this Euclidean definition are you willing to give up in order for your question to make sense on the Earth's surface? Will you curve the sides? Allow them to have unequal lengths? Or allow the angles not to be congruent?

Comment: By a square I meant for all four sides to have the same length and all four corners to be of the same angle.  Is that specific enough?

I would also assume the sides would follow great circles, if that needs to be specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we assume that the Earth is a sphere, you can make the following approximation considering that:

1) The sum of the angles of a triangle on a sphere is 180°(1 + 4f), where f is the fraction of the sphere's surface that is enclosed by the triangle (cfr Wikipedia)

2) one square of 1 km2 on the Earth surface can be made of 2 triangles of 0.5 km2 (note that a square of 1 by 1 km is in fact slightly larger than 1km2. This should be taken into account if your squares are large.)

3) the four angles of the square are equal

4) the area of the Earth is approximately 510,072,000 km2

so each angle in the square are approximately 2*180*(1+4*0.5/510,072,000)/4 = 90.000000353 degree

EDIT: As noted by Whuber, I am talking here about squares (and triangles) in spherical geometry :

> In spherical geometry, a square is a polygon whose edges are great
>   circle arcs of equal distance, which meet at equal angles. Unlike the
>   square of plane geometry, the angles of such a square are larger than
>   a right angle. Larger spherical squares have larger angles.

Comment: And as a check I tried a triangle with 90-deg corners.

A triangle with a 90-deg corner at a pole and two 90-deg corners on the equator would cover 1/4 of one hemisphere, so 1/8 of the earth, and...
180 * (1 + 4 * 1/8) = 270

I like it ;)

Comment: Your assumptions imply, in general, that the sides of this figure will not be equal. Is it still a "square" then?

Comment: @whuber I don't see which assumption implies that the sides will NOT be equal. I did not assume the equality of the four sides, so my answer is valid for all rectangles, but this does not invalidate the results for a square.

Comment: It's not a matter of assumptions, but purely of geometry: except in very special, limited configurations, the figures you talk about simply do not exist! Even the spherical analogs of Cartesian rectangles are problematic. In some sense you are *defining* "squares" as four-sided closed figures with equal angles. But those will not correspond well to the usual idea of a "square" as having four congruent straight sides: something has to give. Since you're not specific about this, your answer becomes somewhat ambiguous.